# How do I go about answering this question on derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$
\begin{align}Find&& f''(2)&&if&&f(x)=x^2f(2x)
&&and 
\end{align}$$ 
$$
\begin{align}
&f(4)=-2,f'(4)=1,f''(4)=-1
\end{align}$$

I have no idea on how to approach this problem, and a step by step explanation would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. I'm looking more for the the process to finding the answer than the actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the chain rule and composite function rule:
$$f(x)=x^2f(2x)$$
$$f'(x)=2xf(2x)+2x^2f'(2x)$$
Where the factor of $2$ in the second term comes from the internal derivative of $2x$. Continuing, we have:
$$f''(x)=2f(2x)+4xf'(2x)+ 4x f'(2x)+ 4x^2f''(2x)$$
Thus:
$$f''(2)=2f(4)+16f'(4)+16f''(4) = -4$$

Answer (score 3):

Based on the chain rule:

$$f'(x)=2xf(2x)+2x^2f'(2x)$$
so
$$f''(x)=2f(2x)+4xf'(2x)+4xf'(2x)+4x^2f''(2x)$$
and with $x=2$ we find
$$f''(2)=2f(4)+16f'(4)+16f''(4)=-4$$

Comment: beat by 11 seconds...